# Example of a quasi compact quasi separated non affine scheme with many global sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Reading about the qcqs lemma in Ravis notes and I'm trying to think of an example where this is interesting.

Comment: What do you mean by "many global sections"? What about $\mathbf A^2 - \{(0,0)\}$?

Comment: @Hoot I guess that satisfies the requirements of my question, but I realize I was secretly hoping for something that didn't embed into its affinization, but had enough global sections to have an interesting affinization. Pretty vague question. Your example is good though, its helpful.

Comment: @Hoot yeah, I guess I want an example where this doesn't obviously follow from the corresponding statement for affine schemes.

Comment: @AreaMan What is 'affinization'? You mean $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X(X))$?